# How to manage the same blog at two sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have two almost-identical sites. Site A has four static pages, and Site B has four static pages, but they *both share a common blog-posts page*.

I need the page URLs to be as follows:

> ```
> http://siteA.com/page1
> http://siteA.com/page2
> http://siteA.com/page3
> http://siteA.com/page4
> http://siteA.com/blog
> ```

And

```
 http://siteB.com/page1
 http://siteB.com/page2
 http://siteB.com/page3
 http://siteB.com/page4
 http://siteB.com/blog (same content as blog page at Site A)
```

What's the best way to do this? Two Wordpress installs, one in each site's root (where one simply accepts the RSS feed from the other)? Or host all the static pages at one site and use redirects from the other site? Or something even more graceful I haven't thought of? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have each install connect to the same database.

The beauty of that is that each could have a different template.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion

Site redirect is  a good option for you because manage two site is more hassle work then one.

and their is no problem comes in SEO ways but search engine don't like duplicate content.

Comment: Isn't redirecting confusing for the user? And what about different side-headers and designs?

Answer (score 0):

You could display the blog in an iframe or pull a cached html copy from siteA to siteB.